# can we use cin>> in member functions in a class in C++?

Tags: c++, cin, member-functions

I'm trying to initialize a class matrix using a member function like thiis

```
class mat{
    int r,c;
    float **p;
    
    public:
    
    mat(){}
    mat(int,int);
    void initialize();
};
mat :: mat (int r, int c){ //check for float and int if error occurs
    p=new float*[r];
    for(int i=0; i<r; ++i){
        p[i]=new float(c);
    }
void mat :: initialize(void){
    int i,j;
    cout<<"\nEnter the elements : ";
    for(i=0;i<r;++i){
        for(j=0;j<c;++j){
            cin>>p[i][j];
        }
    }
}
int main(){
    mat m1(3,3);
    cout<<"\nInitialize M1";
    m1.initialize();
    
    
    return(0);
}
```

but when i compile and run it and try to initialize a matrix, program never stops to recieve inputs.
Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds like your stream is bad. When you're debugging, can you check the value of `std::cin.good()`?

Comment: Where do you call `initialize`?

Comment: I think your bug is here: `p[i]=new float(c);` did you mean to allocate a single float and set it's value to `c` or  allocate `c` floats?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a [mcve]. And also please tell us the input you give the program.

Comment: You're missing a `}` at the end of your constructor, by the way

Comment: @drescherjm Is correct, the code will only work if `c == 1`.

Comment: I think you also need to initialize r and c in constructor

Comment: For the bug I mentioned you need to change `p[i]=new float(c);` to `p[i]=new float[c];`

Comment: You are initializing neither `c` nor `r` in your constructor, so when you call `initialize` their values are indeterminate.

Comment: @drescherjm you were right to point out....i should have used square brackets [ ] instead of ( ) ...it solved my issue.... Thanks a lot

Comment: @scohe001 Sounds to me like the stream is _always good_.

Comment: @tibi thanks for pointing it out..... i missed that too.

Comment: @Rane thanks for pointing that out...i missed that...Thanks a lot!

Comment: You'll find life much easier if you use a [`std::vector<std::vector<float>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of allocating your own arrays - much more of the work is done (and properly) for you.

Comment: Interesting.... what was the reason for choosing _"can we use `cin>>` in member functions in a class in C++?"_ as the title instead of _"can we use nested `for` in member functions in a class in C++_"? (I'd guess the answer is some variant of "jumping to conclusions is fun"?) :)

Comment: @JaMiT i'm not much of a programmer so i'm not familiar with the  right terms to use.... but hey! you do have a point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize `r` and `c` like this:

```
mat :: mat (int r, int c) :r(r), c(c){
    p=new float*[r];
    for(int i=0; i<r; ++i){
        p[i]=new float[c];
    }
}
```

and don't forget to add the destructor.

Comment: It's normal and best practice to use an initialiser list: `mat::mat(int rows, int columns) : r{rows}, c{columns} { ... }`.  And the proper terminology is "destructor" rather than "deconstructor".